# Error: Trying to print out array elements in React Function Component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

**Trying to log array elements, I'm getting the following error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

*However, when I CAN log the project.tasks array object in console. But it can't log the elements.*

The array seems to exist as I can log the object but NOT the elements. I'm confused. Ideas?

CODE SANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mclaren-ll5wo

```
function EditProjectView(props) {
  const [project, setProject] = useState({});

  // get id from params
  const { id } = useParams();

  // syncronously (same time before and then after) renders it will use this hook
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // fake* ajax request to database
    const data = database.projects.find((project) => {
      return project.id == 123;
    }, []);

    setProject(data);
  });

  if (project) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <main style={classes.content}>
          <div style={classes.projectContainer}>
            <div style={classes.projectOverviewWrapper}>
              <Paper elevation={2}>
                <div style={classes.project}>
                  {/* {<ProjectDetailsView project={project} />} */}
                </div>
              </Paper>
            </div>
            <div style={classes.tasksContainer}>
              <h3>ALL TASKS</h3>
              {console.log(
                "prints out array object successfully i.e. [{..}, {..]]  <-------------",
                project.tasks
              )}
              {console.log(
                "does NOT print array object's elements FAIL <-----------",
                project.tasks[0].taskName
              )}
              <TaskExpansionPanel
                panelTitle={
                  <PanelTitle
                  // totalTimeInMinutes={task.totalTimeInMinutes}
                  // taskNumber={task.taskNumber}
                  // taskName={task.taskName}
                  // taskName={project.projectName}
                  />
                }
                panelDetails={<PanelDescription />}
              />
              <CreateTaskBtn />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  } else {
    return <p>loading..</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox with the code?

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mclaren-ll5wo

Comment: Why are you adding console.log statements inside return? Add them before return and inspect what is logging first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
function printTasks(tasks) {
  if (tasks && tasks.length > 0) {
      return ( console.log(tasks[0].taskName));
  } else {
      return "No tasks found";
  }
}
```

and then calling this inside your component in place of your current check.

```
{printTasks(project.tasks)}
```

What I think happens here is that your fetch from the database isn't done first-time component is painted, so it fails. With this check, it will live to see the second update when data is fetched.

Comment: That worked! But I don't see how if(project) fails while if(project.tasks && project.tasks.length > 0) renders? ...if a project exists then its tasks property should as well though? Please explain,

Comment: project.tasks will be false if an array is empty or non-existent. Even project.tasks.length is maybe redundant

Comment: That makes sense. However, project.tasks length is always >0 i'm just database.js (fake data)..you can check the database.js file here: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mclaren-ll5wo   ?

Comment: Yes, but it may not be fetched at the moment component is first mounted?

Comment: Interesting. So it would mean react renders as the data starts coming in from fetch... instead of waiting for the response completion? Going to research this. Are you sure?

Comment: If you have any async operation application will render before it finishes and will re-render once operation returns a result. I'm not sure about this particular case, but in general, that's how it should work